# Is there a way to dynamically apply a CSS to a menu that includes the taxonomy term of the current page

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, routes, javascript, theming

For example, if I have page nodes with a vocabulary called "issues", which has terms, such as "budget", "education" and "foreign policies", and there's a menu titled "Information", I want to be able to add a class to that menu link for each page, such as "budget-info", "education-info" and "foreign-policies-info", dynamically.  I assume I can throw in a JS behavior, but if there's a module that does this so the user can manage the class names assigned to each menu, especially that handles tokens and/or PHP so you can throw in part of the current url, that would be better. Note that I don't want to create a menu from taxonomy terms, but a standard item in the main menu with a custom class name applied which is comprised of a combination of a manually supplied name, and a taxonomy term that comes from current node.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use [Field Formatter CSS](https://drupal.org/project/field_formatter_css_class) Class in some form or fashion, that can add a class to the node based on a taxonomy term, etc.